# Customizable jQuery calendar

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery. Could someone tell me where I can find a nice customizable jQuery calendar? I tried the jQuery UI Date picker, but I can't seem to configure the CSS for it. Is there a better calendar where I can fully configure the CSS or can't I just find it with the one I have. In that case: could you please point me in the

Answer (score 0):

it is not a jquery calender, but i use it alot in my applications and find it very usefull and easy to use.

[Tigra Calender](http://www.softcomplex.com/products/tigra_calendar/)